# Difference between may and might

Tags: grammar, differences

What is the difference between these sentences?

1. You may regret it.
2. You might regret it.

Comment: _may_ suggests slightly more _possibility_ than _might._ Please look for previous posts to find answers to such questions as they've been sufficiently dealt with here before.

Answer (score -1):

We use may and might when we are not sure about something in the present or future; however, may indicates more possibility than might.

1. You may regret it. -> *It is likely that you may regret it.*
2. You might regret it. -> *There is only a possibility that you will regret it but no one is very sure.*